# Partition merge

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Can anyone help me reagrding this? I have a similar kind of partition as shown in the below format.
[7.7 GB New volume: D (Logical drive)][7.8 GB System drive][C: Drive 200GB][715 GB New volume: E (Primary partition)]

I would like to merge the first and the last partition. Is there any possible way that I could do that? Please help. And also, when I install Ubuntu, will I be able to make a new partition from the E drive and install Ubuntu in it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make a screenshot of gparted and past a link to your question.

Comment: I am unable to that because ask ubuntu says I need 10 reputation to do that! :(

Comment: You can upload the image to some image hosting site and post a link here. I will edit your question and add it as an image.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/vw1ikszf1/   (Image from windows)

Comment: This is from Windows. You need to boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB, run gparted and give a screenshot from there. Anyway you will move partitions from LiveUSB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly merge partitions. You can move them, expand or shrink.

In your case you will have to move Windows partitions. But after that Windows will not boot. You will have to restore Windows bootloader.

The easiest way will be to install Ubuntu to the last partition and e.g. make a swap partition of the first one.

IMHO it is not worth effort to move all Windows partition. It takes a lot of time, some skill and it is potentially dangerous for your data.

Another option will be to re-install Windows.
You can wipe your disk, remove existing partitions, install Windows on 1 or 2 partitions at the beginning of the disk.

Then you will be able to create partitions for installing Ubuntu.

Without gparted screenshot it is hard to tell what is extended partition, but I suspect, that it is the first one. It will cause problems.

I would remove the first partition and re-install Windows from disk.

Comment: this is the image from gpart : http://postimg.org/image/cmet111xn/

Comment: i don't have any important data. i don't mind even if i have to reinstall windows!

Comment: i would like to have three or four partitions at the max and i wouldn't want my disk partition to look like the one in the image above. so please advice me what to do. Thanks! :)

Comment: If i just restore it back to the factory setting, will all the data  and partitions be wiped off from my disk?

Comment: Just re-install Windows first. Installer let's you remove and create partitions. Just remove all, create one primary partition at the beginning and install Windows there. Then you will be able to install Ubuntu beside Windows.

Comment: @Dragon I do not think if you restore to factory that first partition is removed. It contains installer.

Comment: So, will the system drive get affected? (the one with the FAT32 file system). And thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Is the installer placed in the drive with FAT32 file system? And if I delete the installer,  is it good or bad?

Comment: @Dragon I do not know what is there installed by the vendor. But if you have a Windows installer DVD, you do not need all that.

Comment: It was a DOS system that I had purchased! So? Will it matter?

Comment: No. It does not. Then you can wipe all partitions and create new ones.